# linear transformation between two bases for the polynomial space $P_2[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$B=\{1,1+x,1+x+x^2\}, C=\{1+x,2x,x^2-1\}$

$B$ and $A$ are both bases for the polynomial space $P_2[x]$.

$T: P_2[x] \to P_2[x]$

$$[T]B = 
\begin{pmatrix}               
3 & 3 & 3\\
-2 & -6 & -6\\
1 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Find $[T(2x^2 +2x+1)]_C$

This is the full question but in Hebrew, you can see the matrix and the bases there as  well.

[image: original_problem_statement_in_Hebrew]

Comment: You need to write $v=2x^2+2x+1$ in the basis $B$ as in $2x^2+2x+1=(-1)1+0(1+x)+2(1+x+x^2)$. This tells you that $v$ has coordinates $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}$ in the basis $B$. Then multiply this vector of coordinates by $[T]_B$ on the left. You get $\begin{pmatrix}3\\-10\\11\end{pmatrix}$, which is the vector of coordinates of $T(v)$ in the basis $B$. Therefore $T(v)=3\cdot 1-10(1+x)+11(1+x+x^2)$. Now write this as a combination of the basis $C$ and the coefficients will form $[T(v)]_C$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @user647486 can you write [Tv]c as well